# Copy and Flatten directory contents with zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I have a directory tree, where each subdirectory contains several different filetypes, I want to copy one particular filetype from each of the subdirectory, but I need to flatten the results, so that they all end up in one directory - only copying the newly added files and preserving permissions I have been using cp under zsh, with the following command line

```
cp -np **/*.ftype ../destination
```

Which has worked brilliantly up until now. However, I've just reached a limit, I'm not sure if it's the number of directories in the source directory (currently 217) or the total number of directories / desired files, (somewhere between 2672 and 2690) but suddenly I'm getting the error `argument list too long: cp`

I was hoping to use something like `cp -np [A-Ma-m]**/*.ftype ../destination` and split the job into parts, but I get `no matches found: [A-Ma-m]**/*.ftype` even though I know I have directories starting with the these ranges.

I've also tried

```
find Base_dir/ -iname '*.ftype' | xargs -J% cp -np % ../destination
```

but it seems to break the directories at each point that there's a space character in the name, so it copies nothing.

I'm sure I'm doing something silly wrong, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I try using `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`. Also, read the _manual page_ of each _command_.

Comment: @user3439894  Thanks, it's close, however, it has one minor problem:-  If I have 2 files within the folder with the same name, but different extentions, for instance fred.ftype and fred.bar, both files are copied to the destination folder.

Comment: Dominic Strange, Without seeing the actual _command_ you used, the only thing I can say is when I use e.g. `find . -iname '*.ftype' -print0` it only returns `fred.ftype` under the same scenario you presented in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The length of a command line in a shell is limited, probably to something like 65536 characters. So if your pattern expand to more characters than that, you'll get the "argument list too long" error you mentioned.

In such cases, `find` is the better approach (it will then also work for users of other shells). The copy can be accomplished with one of

```
find base_dir/ -iname '*.ftype' -print0 | xargs -0 -J% cp -np % dest_dir/
find base_dir/ -iname '*.ftype' -exec cp '{}' dest_dir/ \;
```

PS: The quoting in `-iname '*.ftype'` is important here to avoid expansion by the shell.

PPS: The error you get when using `[A-Ma-m]**/*.ftype` indicates that the pattern didn't get expanded. I don't know `zsh` very well, but most likely `**` doesn't support additional patterns in front.

Comment: Thanks, the second variant works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

“Argument list too long” is due to the total length of the command line (the command name and the arguments, plus one byte for each — plus the environment, actually). It is limited to [`sysctl kern.argmax`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) bytes (`KERN_ARGMAX` in the [C `sysctl` interface](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)). The usual way to get around this error is to split the command into multiple calls.

Zsh commes with a function called [`zargs`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs) which helps with automatically running a command multiple times with successive sets of arguments. It's similar to the external command [`xargs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) but a different syntax.

```
autoload -U zargs
zargs -i -- **/*.ftype -- cp -- {} ../destination
```

Put the `autoload` line in your `~/.zshrc` to avoid having to type it each time you want to use it. (Some zsh configuration frameworks may do it for you.)

The option `-i` causes `zargs` to replace `{}` in the command by each argument in turn. This runs `cp` once per argument. `zargs` can also run the command with multiple arguments at a time, which is faster, but a limitation is that the grouped arguments have to go at the end of the command line. This is not a good match for `cp` since it needs the destination to go at the end.

[GNU `cp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation) has an option `-T` which allows the destination to be passed before the sources, precisely to facilitate the use of `xargs` (and `zargs` which is similar). Assuming you have GNU `cp` installed as `gcp`:

```
zargs -- **/*.ftype -- cp -T ../destination --
```

Alternatively, an advantage of `zargs` over `xargs` is that you can use it on a function.

```
f () { $@[2,-1] $1 }
zargs -- **/*.ftype -- f ../destination cp --
```

Note how `f` only reorders its arguments, it doesn't have the `cp -- … ../destination` built in. The point is to keep the `f` call at least as long as the `cp` call, otherwise `zargs` would build a command line that goes over the limit when the `cp --` and `../destination` parts are added. Alternatively, pass a smaller limit:

```
f () { cp -- "$@" ../destination/; }
zargs -s $(($(sysctl kern.argmax) - $#functions[f])) -- **/*.ftype -- f
```

(or just type a limit, e.g. `zargs -s 999999 -- **/*.ftype -- f`).

Alternatively, stop worrying about the command line length limit and use the [`zcp` function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zcp) to do fancy copies. As before, put the `autoload` and `alias` lines in your `.zshrc` to avoid having to type them each time.

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
zcp '**/(*.ftype)' '../destination/$1'
```